# List of lists, how can i do calculations with specific numbers in each list?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a function:

```
def readCSVfile(str1):
```

This function takes a CSV file that the user chooses and reads it.
Each file contains a list of list that looks like this:

```
[[1, 1, 2.2, 1.3, 9.6], [1, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 7.6], [1, 3, 2.7, 1.5, 2.2], [2, 1, 3.0, 4.5, 1.5], [2, 2, 3.1, 3.1, 4.0], [2, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.0], [3, 1, 1.9, 1.8, 4.5], [3, 2, 1.1, 0.5, 2.3], [3, 3, 3.5, 2.0, 7.5], [4, 1, 2.9, 2.7, 3.2], [4, 2, 4.5, 4.8, 6.5], [4, 3, 1.2, 1.8, 2.7]]
```

Now, after the user have chosen a file the job is to make the program print out some calculations from each list made by my program but i am stuck.
Say for example that i want to multiply the third and the fourth number in each list, how would i specify that?

Trying to do something like

```
readCSVfile(str1)[2]
```

Don't work.
I have googled like crazy

Comment: as your function suggests, it seems you read the data in as string/buffer, which isn't a valid python **list** so to speak, try converting them to python list, and try again. If you are only interested in result of each multiples of sub-list, just use list comprehension.

Comment: import ast ast.literal_eval('["A","B" ,"C" ," D"]')

Answer (score 0):

```
through map and a lambda as one way:

li = [[1, 1, 2.2, 1.3, 9.6], [1, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 7.6], [1, 3, 2.7, 1.5, 2.2], [2, 1, 3.0, 4.5, 1.5], [2, 2, 3.1, 3.1, 4.0], [2, 3, 2.5, 2.8, 3.0], [3, 1, 1.9, 1.8, 4.5], [3, 2, 1.1, 0.5, 2.3], [3, 3, 3.5, 2.0, 7.5], [4, 1, 2.9, 2.7, 3.2], [4, 2, 4.5, 4.8, 6.5], [4, 3, 1.2, 1.8, 2.7]]

for el in map(lambda x: [x[0], x[1], round(x[2] * x[3],2),x[4]],li):
    print(el)

[1, 1, 2.86, 9.6]
[1, 2, 4.62, 7.6]
[1, 3, 4.05, 2.2]
[2, 1, 13.5, 1.5]
[2, 2, 9.61, 4.0]
[2, 3, 7.0, 3.0]
[3, 1, 3.42, 4.5]
[3, 2, 0.55, 2.3]
[3, 3, 7.0, 7.5]
[4, 1, 7.83, 3.2]
[4, 2, 21.6, 6.5]
[4, 3, 2.16, 2.7]
```

Comment: Thing is, only thing i have to work with at moment is my readCSVfile(str1).
I do not have the lists written out in the code!

Comment: @ErikAngerfistNyström is sublist in your list a row in your csv file?

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [ [1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]

for x in range(len(lst)):
    print(lst[x][2] * lst[x][3])
```